# Page title not showing on google search due to embedded videos

Tags: google-search, title, youtube

I have two pages on my website, both have one embedded youtube video each.
But on google search engine, original page titles are not showing rather some garbage titles are showing. Look at the picture below,

[image: Google search screenshot]

If you want to check the html source links to both pages are as follows,

[First link](http://chatclub.unaux.com/blogs/1/How%20to%20chat%20on%20chatclub.unaux.com)

[Second link](http://chatclub.unaux.com/blogs/2/How%20to%20make%20a%20blog%20on%20chatclub.unaux.com)

What could be the reason page titles are not showing on google search ?

Here is the screenshot of tested page from google search console of one of the page,

[image: Google search console screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried inspecting those URLs in Google Search Console and and trying a live test?  That would show you exactly how Googlebot views the pages.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I did that in search console and the videos were not loading in the screenshot, but normally when you visit the link video loads, why are google bots giving error "Your browser can't play this video" ?

Comment: When they were not loading in the screenshot did that error message appear on the page?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I edited my question and includes the screenshot from google search console, you can see video didnt load.